# AutoLayout for iPhone 4s,5,5s,6,6+ xcode how to achieve this?

Tags: autolayout, xcode6

I am using storyboard for Designing screens i cant able to set autolayout for 3.5inch and 4 inch screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can check WWDC 2014 video 401 - What's New in XCode 6. http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/401xxfkzfrjyb93/401/401_sd_whats_new_in_xcode_6.mov?dl=1

You can select a view from storyboard and then use preview option to see device specific UI and add specific constraints.